# Sys.path.append("") Dosen't work on Debian.. :/ "no module named guess_language"

Tags: android, python, sqlite, debian, raspberry-pi

Just transferred my python project by ftp to my linux server
and the project can't import files some what.. :/

```
sys.path.append("Functions\guess_language")
import check_language
sys.path.append("Functions\SL4A")
import android
```

It's doesn't let me to import any module, but In windows, It does work..
why? I'm using Python 2.7 btw.

Thanks.

Comment: backslashes are escape chars

Comment: Did you try absolute path's?

Comment: Thank you so much @Corey Goldbery, It works! I though all the slashes are the same, thanks again!!

Comment: i added my comment as an answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

backslashes are escape characters in strings.

so you have a few choices to deal with that in your example...

1. use raw strings:

   sys.path.append(r"Functions\guess_language")
2. escape the backslash with another backslash:

   sys.path.append("Functions\\guess_language")
3. use forward slashes:

   sys.path.append("Functions/guess_language")
4. use os.path.join:

   sys.path.append(os.path.join("Functions", "guess_language"))
5. string formatting with os.sep:

   sys.path.append('Functions%sguess_language' % os.sep)

Comment: Choice 4: Use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: @Matthias, hah, updated answer.  you could also use ''.join('Functions', os.sep, 'guess_language')  ... or perhaps: 'Functions%sguess_language' % os.sep